# Bigtable row key - start with date only?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Bigtable docs warn against monotonically increasing row keys, like timestamps.

What about this situation:

- The row key starts with a date and ends with a random GUID (ex. `2017-01-01#563d7104-f976-40a2-b0d5-a1b6083c73f4`)
- Within a 24 hour period, writes and reads have the same date, for the most part

Would this cause an issue, or would Bigtable efficiently split nodes across the current date once it realizes that most reads/writes are on the same date for a 24 hour period?

I need to query on date, so it seems like it's either this or a shard identifier at the start (ex. `A#2017-01-01#563d7104-f976-40a2-b0d5-a1b6083c73f4`). A shard identifier makes queries more complex, so I'd like to use it only if I need to.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you need to scan sequential rows, or are you only doing random point reads/writes?

Comment: My use case is a lot of writes with the same date stamp (same date stamp for 24 hour period) -- the date will be the same, but GUID after the date will be different with each write. Then I do a scan for all rows on the same date. Using Dataflow for writes and reads.

Comment: Also wondering if I could place the date at the end of the row key and do a RowKeyFilter with a wildcard like `*#2017-01-01`. That way the writes would be dispersed across the tablets, but I'm not sure how efficient the query would be.

Comment: If you always store date-based data, and you don't need random-reads, but always want to read the entire dataset for the whole day, you may be better off using date-partitioned tables with BigQuery rather than Bigtable. Also, if you place the date at the end of the row key (using your example of `*#2017-01-01`), that will require a full table scan on Bigtable, so not very efficient. I think date-partitioned BigQuery tables would be more appropriate for this specific use case, since you want to scan the entire day's data all the time via Dataflow, rather than access a specific row.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, prefixing your row keys with a date or timestamp is an antipattern in Bigtable, because on every new day, all the new reads and writes will go to a single new tablet, which will become a hotspot for the Bigtable cluster.

Ideally, you should put the date or timestamp at the end of your row key and use a primary identifier, such as a hash of a user account or a device id, as the prefix.

This assumes that you only do random reads and writes in Bigtable, and you don't need to scan the entire day's worth of data (which a date prefix allows you to do), or if you need to scan a date range (find all data from date A to date B).

If your use case is primarily date-based full scans, BigQuery with date-partitioned tables may be a better approach. If you need only random reads and random writes, you will be better off putting the date as a suffix.

Additionally, if the number of requests you are sending to Bigtable is relatively small — e.g., hundreds or low single-digit thousands requests/sec, you may be able to go with the date-prefix and it will work just fine, but be careful if you decide to significantly scale up, because you won't be able to do hundreds of thousands of requests/sec with this schema design.

If you can provide more clarification on your use case (see comment with question), that would also be helpful to guide the answer.